# holding values types in textarea in meteor when it is submitted

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, textarea, submit

```js
Template.body.events({
  'submit .new-resolution': function(event) {
    var title = event.target.title.value;
    var ts = Date.now() / 1000;

    Resolutions.insert({

      title: title

    });

    event.target.title.value = "";

    return false;


  }

});
```

```html
<body>

  
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Comment Box</h1>
      <form class="new-resolution">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter comment...">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
      </form>
    </header>

  </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to get values on screen but whenever I click on submit the values are not getting displayed on screen.

I tried using **return event.preventDefault();** as well but this is not working. This is a small piece of code of my project.

So can anyone tell what's wrong with code or is there any meteor version issue?

Comment: My meteor version is Meteor 1.4.4.1

Comment: All your code is doing is taking the value from the input and inserting it in to the database. There is no code there to display the value you are retrieving from the input, what do you mean by you want to 'display it on the screen'?

Comment: I've posted the code again

Comment: Are you using the meteor package ```autopublish```?

Comment: yes, I'm using autopublish and whenever I enter anything into textarea the page gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('resolutions');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var registerData = {
        email: event.target.registerEmail.value,
        password: event.target.registerPassword.value
      }

      Accounts.createUser(registerData, function(error) {
        if (Meteor.user()) {
          console.log(Meteor.userId());
        } else {
          console.log("ERROR: " + error.reason);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  Template.login.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var myEmail = event.target.loginEmail.value;
      var myPassword = event.target.loginPassword.value;

      Meteor.loginWithPassword(myEmail, myPassword, function(error) {
        if (Meteor.user()) {
          console.log(Meteor.userId());
        } else {
          console.log("ERROR: " + error.reason);
        }
      });
    }
  });



  Template.home.events({
    'click .logout': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      Meteor.logout(function(error) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("ERROR: " + error.reason);
        }
      });
    }
  });




  Template.body.helpers({
    resolutions: function() {
      return Resolutions.find();

    }

  });

  Template.body.events({
    'submit new-resolution': function(event) {


      var title = event.target.title.value;
      var ts = Date.now() / 1000;

      Resolutions.insert({

        title: title,
        user: myEmail

      });

      event.target.title.value = "";


      return false;

    }

  });

}
```

```html
<body>

  {{#if currentUser}} {{> home}}
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Comment Box</h1>
      <form class="new-resolution">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter comment...">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
      </form>
    </header>

    {{#each resolutions}} {{> resolution}} {{/each}}

  </div>


  {{else}} {{> register}} {{> login}} {{/if}}



</body>



<template name="register">
   <h2>REGISTER:</h2>
   <form>
      <input type = "email" name = "registerEmail"><br>
      <input type = "password" name = "registerPassword"><br>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Register"><br>
   </form>
</template>

<template name="login">
   <h2>LOGIN:</h2>
   <form>
      <input type = "email" name = "loginEmail"><br>
      <input type = "password" name="loginPassword"><br>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Login"><br>
   </form>
</template>



<template name="resolution">
 <h5> {{title}} </h5>
</template>

<template name="home">
 <button class = "logout">Logout</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
Template.body.events({
    'submit new-resolution': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //this stops the page from reloading

        var title = event.target.title.value;
        var ts = Date.now() / 1000;

        Resolutions.insert({
            title: title,
            user: myEmail
        });

        event.target.title.value = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: But whenever I enter any value and submit it's not displaying anything. (As it is suppose to display the entered value). And now I'm totally lost, tried each and everything.

Comment: Is it inserting in to the database?

Comment: I guess it is not and why is it so?
I checked through console and it showed me this......
Object { collection: Object, sorter: null, matcher: Object, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined, limit: undefined, fields: undefined, _projectionFn: require<.node_modules.meteor.minimongo["projection.js"]</LocalCollection._compileProjection/<(), _transform: null, reactive: true }

Comment: I haven't installed node js

Comment: You can't run Meteor without node installed, so you definitely do have it installed. I suggest you run through the Meteor tutorial as it seems you don't understand the basics: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app